# Is there any JAX-WS implementation that support dynamic namespace in generated client?

Tags: web-services, namespaces, jax-ws, wsimport

I generated a JAX-WS client (proxy API) using JAXWS-RI wsimport.bat from a WSDL having as namespace "http://a.mydomain".
 I'd like to reuse the same generated proxy against a service having as namespace "http://b.mydomain" but targetnamespace "http://a.mydomain" is harcoded all over the generated classes.

Does anybody know any good solution to this problem using JAXWS-RI or any other JAXWS implementation ? I'd like to prevent from regenerating proxy classes using the new WSDL/namespace.

Thank you for any piece of answer.

Answer (score 1):

Steps include:

1. Create the Service instance using the Service.create method
   for which you need to know wsdl location, service name, and name space URL of the service.
   e.g.
   URL wsdlLocation = new URL("http://example.org/my.wsdl");
   QName serviceName = new QName("http://example.org/sample", "MyService");
   Service s = Service.create(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
2. Get the service proxy (service port for connecting) using Service.getPort() method.
   For this you need to know endpoint implemenattion class name.
   e.g. MyService port = s.getPort(MyService.class);

you can now call methods through proxy.
change the name space URL as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The Jax-ws RI does create a constructor like this:

```
public SomeWebServiceEndpoint(URL wsdlLocation, QName serviceName)
```

In the QName element you can specify a namespace during runtime (or use a different WSDL location, for example PROD or TEST).

So you either can subclass your webservice into a new class, or use a different wrapper to call them.